# How to triage a question that demonstrates profound lack of knowledge

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, triage

This is with regard to this question, which just came up in my triage queue:

[Getting strings from an array inside a function, located on a different php page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42567413/getting-strings-from-an-array-inside-a-function-located-on-a-different-php-page)

The question demonstrates, to my mind, a lack of understanding of the programming language - the code is just nonsensical. I wanted to mark it "unsalvageable", but there isn't a "close" reason that seems to match this situation.

How should a reviewer respond to a question that demonstrates a fundamental lack of understanding of the technology being asked about?

Comment: If the amount of explanation required to adequately cover the topic requested would be too large for an answer, it's too broad.

Answer (score 3):

Think of these things in triage:

- **As the question is written**, is there any editing that could be done to improve its clarity that isn't exclusively needed by the OP?
- **As the question is written**, is there a clear question and a clear objective?
- **As the question is written**, is there any way that an answer could be formulated?

Regardless of whether or not the OP seems to have a grasp at understanding the language*, your objective in triage is to see if the question can or cannot be saved by any reasonable efforts - namely editing - by someone that isn't the OP.  If you feel that it can be saved with some editing to make the question clearer, then do so; if you don't, then state so accordingly in triage.

If you're just not a fan of the question, feel free to downvote.  No reason to bother closing it if no close reason available fits.

<sup>*: Let's be honest.  If one is asking a syntax-related question, then one probably doesn't have the best grip on the language.  But that's not something that should be *punished* by having a close reason (which existed and was abused, by the way) that says this kind of thing.</sup>

Comment: So, we should "punish" the people that read the questions with gravel, right?

Comment: There's really no reason to punish anyone in that scenario.  Just because a user may or may not have a complete grasp on the language isn't an excuse to regard them any differently than if someone *did* have a grasp on the language.  What matters is that they're asking a question, which is them ***admitting*** that they don't know something.  In the eyes of triage, this is, naturally, irrelevant; question *quality* is what the goal is there.

Comment: Just because a user may or may not have a complete grasp on the language isn't a excuse to make us to hold their hand through all the process. This site is for professionals/enthusiast. I haven't seen any of those two groups not grabbing the references/manuals/books/etc. before asking others to invest their time in his problem.

Comment: Trivia: I had *no idea* that Python had two division operators before joining Stack Overflow. Hard to tell what someone won't know. Aside: more intro to web-dev courses would benefit from going over the basics of how asynchronous requests work; model on which the web is built is totally unfamiliar to a huge number of programmers, even after so many years. (I suspect this is the root cause of a lot of JavaScript hate as well)

Comment: I really wish we could stop talking about closing as punishment... No wonder new users freak out when they get their question closed.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: I never called closure itself punishment.  However, closure with a reason of, "you're not good enough at programming for us to help" *is* more punishing than is being admitted.